# loop minute in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I have code like this:

```
var hour = 7;
for (var i = 0;i <= 1; i++ ){
  var minute = 0;
  console.log((i + hour) % 24);
}
```

when I run it, I get result like this:

```
7
8
```

my question: how to add the value in format minute ex: `0-59`

so I wanna loop the data like this:

```
7:0
7:1
7:2
s.d
7:59
8:0
```

Comment: Can you show us your loop? I really didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: please add the data source and the access part.

Comment: You should change the title to something like "Check Javascript array for duplicate values"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a new array to store all your unique values. You will need to look into the new "uniques" array, if the value alreay exists and then use the default value:

```
var number= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "6"];
var default = 0;
var uniques = [];
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i < number.length; i++) {
   if(!inArray(number[i], uniques) {
       uniques.push(number[i]);
       result.push(number[i]);
       console.log(number[i]);
   } else {
       console.log(default);
       result.push(default);
   }
}

function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and check against the actual index. If you get the same index, then show the element, otherwise use a default value instead.

```js
var number= ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "6"];
for (var i = 0; i < number.length;i++) {
   console.log(number.indexOf(number[i]) === i ? number[i] : undefined);
}
```

Comment: var db = [
        {status: "5"},
        {status: "6"},
        {status: "7"},
        {status: "7"},
        {status: "7"},
]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the new array, and in the callback store each item in a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to know if it's a duplicate or not.

```js
var number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "6"];
var s = new Set();
console.log(number.map(n => s.has(n) ? undefined : s.add(n) && n));
```

If the non-equality of your values is respected by stringification, you can use a plain object, without needing ES6 features:

```js
var number = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "6"];
var s = Object.create(null);
console.log(number.map(function(n) {
  if (n in s) return undefined;
  s[n] = true;
  return n;
}));
```

Comment: how if use variabel object not array?                                                    var number = [
        {status: "5"},
        {status: "6"},
        {status: "7"},
        {status: "7"},
        {status: "7"},
]